# extensive JS in php-file with buffering - how

Tags: php, javascript

I'm including a great deal of (partly server-generated) JS in a php.file.

What's the best approach?

I know there's something like ">>>excerpt" or something that just let me type anything,
but I forgotten..

Regards,
//t

Comment: Why is this necessary? It is not an option to put this into a static JS file?

Comment: No, since partly server-generated stuff inside the js.

Comment: (generated by the php itself that is, not 3:rd part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$html =<<<HTML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

... The rest of your HTML...

And a PHP {$variable} here and an array {$arr['value']} there.

HTML; // End of html variable

// Print this HTML
echo $html
?>
```

Comment: Hmm.. You're not answering my question. To clarify, it's a google-maps application and I'm loading hundreds of markers from php. I know I can use XML to load them seperatly, but the view loading the maps-api already knows the points, so no need for an extra roundtrip to the server.

Comment: Welcome - Didn't realise you were being so specific :)

Answer (score 0):

Decouple the generated part from the static part and generate it either inline or as one other external JS.